# Count on a UNION with Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have the following eloquent query:

```
$x = DB::table("x")->select("x.*");   
$y = DB::table("x")->select("x.*");   

$union = $x->union($y);
```

However if I do

```
$union->count();
```

it fails saying:

```
Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Please, note I'm using table x twice for the union.

From what I understand it's applying the count to the first table rather than to the whole union.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$x = DB::table("x")->select("x.*")->get();
$y = DB::table("x")->select("x.*")->get();

$union = $x->union($y);
```